# JSData `where` does not work with `dataStore.findAll()`

Tags: javascript, jsdata

If I call `dataStore.findAll(mapperName, params, opts)` where `params` is

```
{
  where: {
   cc: {
     '===': 'test'
   }
  },
}
```

I expect the resulting query string to be `?cc=test`. However, it seems to encode the whole object as the resulting query string is `?where=%7B%22cc%22:%7B%22%3D%3D%3D%22:%22test%22%7D%7D`. Does JSData's query feature not work with the http adapter?

This is on `js-data` and `js-data-http` v3

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is the [`filter` syntax](http://api.js-data.io/js-data/latest/Collection.html#filter), whereas you should be able to do the following for [`findAll` syntax](http://api.js-data.io/js-data/latest/SimpleStore.html#findAll):

`{cc: 'test'}`